# Facing a problem in inserting economic calendar from investing.com

Tags: html, iframe

I added a calendar via https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/
by adding

```html
<iframe src="https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone&countries=25,32,6,37,72,22,17,39,14,10,35,43,56,36,110,11,26,12,4,5&calType=week&timeZone=8&lang=1"
  width="650"
  height="467"
  frameborder="0"
  allowtransparency="true"
  marginwidth="0"
  marginheight="0"
></iframe>
```

I got this
[image: output]

But was expecting this
[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected, you probably created a typo in the 'generate html' when placing in your page, as indeed, that code shows an empty `iframe`.
I did not check for differences between yours and mine...

**Update** checking for differences, I noticed that your `<iframe>` contains `https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com` and my `<iframe>` contains `https://sslecal2.investing.com`.
I am not sure why the 'generate html' comes up with different links, but your empty page may be due to some delay on the investor server as now, both links work in Firefox.

```html
<iframe src="https://sslecal2.investing.com?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone&countries=25,32,6,37,72,22,17,39,14,10,35,43,56,36,110,11,26,12,4,5&calType=week&timeZone=8&lang=1"
  width="650" height="467" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
<div class="poweredBy" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">Real Time Economic Calendar provided by <a href="https://www.investing.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Investing.com</a>.</span></div>
```

**OP original link posted above**

```html
<iframe src="https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone&countries=25,32,6,37,72,22,17,39,14,10,35,43,56,36,110,11,26,12,4,5&calType=week&timeZone=8&lang=1"
  width="650" height="467" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
<div class="poweredBy" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">Real Time Economic Calendar provided by <a href="https://www.investing.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Investing.com</a>.</span></div>
```

Comment: There seems to be something else. I copied the webpage generated link and the code provided by you. Both had the same issue as in the OP image. Nonetheless, it works in the snippet.

Comment: @NicolasSilva updated my answer, seems some server issue/hickup.